# killing linux process in status D

Tags: linux, io, scheduler, affinity

I recently had some problems with a process
in **status D** under linux.

I was unable to kill them using any signal and have since learned that this is not
possible at all.

My questions is:

If I use `taskset` to pin a process to a cpu, and then disable that core using

`/sys/devices/system/cpuX/online`,

can I somehow prevent the  scheduler from rescheduling that (stalled) **status-D process** onto the
still available CPUs, so that it is ultimately killed by force ?

Kind Regards,

Stefan

Answer (score 2):

Well, a process in D state is not scheduled. The scheduler skips it, so it doesn't waste resources on a process that it's waiting for, generally, an I/O event. But still, interesting question. I'd like to hear a more technical explanation on this.

Comment: Thanks ! Mmm. When i changed the affinity via taskset, then the list of allowed cpus has changed. Is this not done via scheduler-code ?

Comment: To be honest, I don't know. But it's an interesting question, and I'll try to look it up and provide you an answer.